# what is the right way to query a manytomany field in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

so i have a model which is,

```
class Category(SmartModel):
    item=models.ManyToManyField(Item)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=64,help_text="Title of category e.g BreakFast")
    description=models.CharField(max_length=64,help_text="Describe the category e.g the items included in the category")
    #show_description=check box if description should be displayed
    #active=check box if category is still avialable
    display_order=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s %s %s " % (self.item,self.title, self.description, self.display_order)
```

and as you may see, it has a manytomany field

```
item=models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

i want to return all the items in a template, here is my views.py for this

```
def menu(request):
    categorys= Category.objects.all()
    items= categorys.all().prefetch_related('item')
    context={
        'items':items,
        'categorys':categorys
    }
    return render_to_response('menu.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

here is how am doing it in the templates,

```
    <ul>
{% for item in items %}
 <li>{{ item.item }}

 </li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

after all this,this is what it is returning in my web page,

```
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0xa298b0c>
```

what am i doing wrong,I have really looked around but all in vain, hoping you can help me out and thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly, you have a many to many manager. You need to actually query something... like `all()`

```
{% for item in items %}
   {% for i in item.item.all %}
        {{ i }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Based on your variable naming, I think you're confusing the results of `prefetch_related` as a bunch of `item`s. It is in fact returning a QuerySet of Category objects.

So it would be more intuitive to call them categories.

```
{% for category in categories %}
   {% for item in category.item.all %} 
       {{ item }} {# ...etc #}
```

Comment: i did work on the variables aswel, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
categorys= Category.objects.prefetch_related('item').all()
```

And then in template:

```
{% for category in categorys %}
    {% for item in category.item.all %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: yes, you are right, I forgot about ".item.all" - Yuri showed you exact way :)